# Mongodb Range Based sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I would like to shard my collection on the basis of range on mongodb shards, my question is if shard key is string field then how will we divide string based shard key in different chunks for range based sharding ???

Answer (score 1):

You can divide a string across shards using tag aware sharding. You create the "tags" denoting the ranges of the key to assign to a specific shard. Mongo's balancer will handle the distribution of the data and when you write a query for the key in question Mongo will know to target only that shard.

For more information see the following URL from the vendor. [sharding-introduction/](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/)

Comment: I know about tag aware sharding but if  I have to use tag aware sharding anyway then why is there a seperate range based sharding or range base sharding is just for numeric types ???